# Full Screenbackground Image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, uiimage

I currently try to get a fullscreen background for my iOS Project this means the image should stretch over the full background.
I currently try 2 things but won't worked out as solution.

1)

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
```

This only set the background image on the actual image size and repeat it in x and y, it does not stretch the image to fullscreensize.

2)

use a UIImage and make it equal to width and height and use aspect fill, this also does not give the wanted solution and also use much memory

Is there any other way to get this done?

Comment: Have you tried using constraints? Or is that what you were referring to in part 2?

Comment: Yes i did but it missing some part of the image on the right side then @Glynbeard

Comment: @FabianBoulegue have you tried to use "Scale to fill"?

Comment: @Erik yes but this still cut of 2 edges with equal to width and height

Comment: @FabianBoulegue try to keep it as it is, while ctrl + click & drag from the image to the image and select width, do the same for height. To keep the same height and width

Comment: @Erik but then the image is 31*31px and not fullscreen ;)?

Comment: @FabianBoulegue, oh I see - sorry;) do what I told you about ctrl + dragging, but make sure the image is exactly the size you want it as it'll remain with that size on runtime

Comment: @Erik the problem is it should fit on ipad as well as on iphone as fullscreen ;)

Comment: @FabianBoulegue do you got 2 storyboards? Then I think you could do the same just alter the size in IB after the 2 devices.

Comment: @Erik no i m currently using auto layout so only one storyboard that fit for all devices

Comment: @FabianBoulegue, hard to say what to do then. Never done it before. Perhaps you could set a frame with the right size in the viewWillAppear code? Detect device type and set size accordingly

Comment: @FabianBoulegue or set a new constant value for the width and height constraints depending on device type

Comment: make the constraint of height and width an inequality, but also make sure that the actual UIImage is using the full screen in the Xib file before adding the constraint. 

I had this issue before when learning to use Auto Constraints

Comment: @StevenHernandez what you mean by "make the constraint of height and width an inequality" the UIImage cover the complete screen, after this i add equal with height and width

Comment: Exactly when you add those it gets the EXACT height and width regardless of the device. But if you add an Inequality this will make sure to adjust to new Device Sizes. let me show you with a picture.

Comment: Or also just add Leading and Traling space as constraints and avoid setting Height and width explicitly for it to grab the whole background for multiple screens

Answer (score 1):

So you have two ways to do it always with AutoLayout

1) With an addition of an Inequality constraint like shown in the images below.

2) Or by adding Leading, Trailing space and Top, bottom space Constraint and centering vertically and horizontally constraints but NO explicit height nor width constraint.

[image: Menu]
[image: Inequality]
[image]